# solr filter how i can create filter with and

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I am using http solr server and solrj both version 4.3.1. Now i have got problem with operator AND in my filter query so for example this is my query log :

```
path=/select params={start=1&q=file_content:hello*&wt=javabin&fq=file_create_user:\-1+AND+file_parents_folder:\(341\+AND\+4222\)&version=2&rows=25} status=400 QTime=2
```

And i have got exception:

`Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Invalid Number: (341 AND 4222`)

Whats is wrong in my filter query ? file_parents_folder is multi valued field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of options here:

1. Wrap the filter query in parentheses

   `fq=\(file_create_user:\-1+AND+file_parents_folder:\(341\+AND\+4222\)\)`
2. You can specify the `&fq` parameter multiple times.

   `fq=file_create_user:\-1&fq=file_parents_folder:\(341\+AND\+4222\)`

Comment: I try to add breakes so now this is my query : path=/select params={start=1&q=file_content:hello*&wt=javabin&fq=(file_create_user:\-1+AND+file_parents_folder:\(341\+AND\+4261\))&version=2&rows=25} status=400 QTime=11. But i still have got the same error